# Bullet points not printed in IE8/9 without ticking "Print Background Colors and Images"

Tags: html, css, printing

I made the following jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hxsy6/

The issue I have is that if you print the page in IE7 the bullet points gets printed (the actual bullet image) but if you do that in IE8/9 they don't. However, if I in IE8/9 go to Print Preview -> click the settings icon and tick "Print Background Colors and Images" then they get printed in these two browsers (haven't checked with other browsers yet). In IE7 it doesn't matter if the checkbox is ticked or not.

Any ideas on how to alter the CSS so that an IE8/9 user doesn't have to tick this box, just like with IE7?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: never mind the margin/padding etc., it was just a quick mock-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an IE7 bug to me considering that the images you wish to print are background images. The closest you are going to get is to add a print stylesheet that uses regular CSS bullet points instead of the images.

Comment: with more modern browsers it's possible to do li:before {content: " - "} but of course not with IE7/8 so I had to stick with regular CSS bullets for print.